# how to use variable inside sum function in xslt

Tags: xslt

I am actually looping the field names and calculating the sum of each fields in the xml resultset. Below is my code but I am not able to succeed if any of the value is null in one of the record. kindly help me as soon as possible.

```html
  <xsl:variable name="currentRecord" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="/fkdata/body/attinfofields/row">        
    <xsl:variable name="fld_name" select="translate(fieldname, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" />
    <xsl:variable name="datatype" select="datatype" />
    <xsl:variable name="istotalrequired" select="istotalrequired" />       
    
    <xsl:if test="$datatype='time' and istotalrequired='1'">
      <td nowrap="true">
        <xsl:call-template name="getTime">
          <xsl:with-param name="minutes">
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(/fkdata/body/attrow/row/child::*[name()=$fld_name])" />
          </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </td>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: It's quite not clear what you would like to do. Please post the input XML, the expected output and more of your XSLT so that we can run an example.

Comment: observe the below line. I want the sum of it even if some values in result set are null:   <xsl:value-of select="sum(/fkdata/body/attrow/row/child::*[name()=$fld_name])" />

Comment: I am afraid that we can't help if you don't provide the requested information - namely a fully runnable sample.

Comment: How does a "null value" look like exactly in your input, is that an empty element `<foo/>` or does it contain null `<foo>null</foo>`?

Comment: Any way thanks for both  potame and  Martin Honnen for a quick reponse. I found a solution which i am going to post answer

Answer (score 0):

@ Martin Honnen,

It was an empty element. Actually in our application the xml is generated by the resultset of sql query. So to solve the issue I used **select isnull(abc,0) as foo from tblxyz** in sql query. this solved my problem. May be there was a solution in xsl too but I did it from backend.